# UIBarStyleBlack vs tintColor black

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

What is the difference between setting the `tintColor` property of `UINavigationBar` to `[UIColor blackColor]` and setting `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack` on opaque navigation bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few subtle differences. For example, on iPad, you get a matte style with the tint color, but a glossy one with the `barStyle`.

Also, the color of bordered `UIBarButtonItem`s is slightly different; with the black `barStyle`, they are gray, which makes it easier to distinguish the darker highlighted state, while with a black tint color, the buttons look almost identical in normal and highlighted state.

I think `UIBarButtonItem`s with 'Done' style also look different, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 options for `barStyle`: default and black. However, you can set the `tintColor` to anything you like: red, blue, green, orange, some funny rgb defined color, etc. The default `tintColor` for `UIBarStyleBlack` is, not surprisingly, `[UIColor blackColor]`.

I recommend you just play around with how they look. Set the tint to something fun and toggle between styles. See what you prefer for your app.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not really answer the question I asked.