# how to change the color/style of the toolbar that comes with the UInavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I want to change the colour of the toolbar to Black from the default blue. How do I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the [barStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarStyle) on the [UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) to UIBarStyleBlack:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

If you need to set it to some other color, you will need to set the [tintColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) property:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146151/uibarstyleblack-vs-tintcolor-black) if you interested in the benefits of UIBarStyleBlack over a [UIColor blackColor] tintColor.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code. You can change the color of navigationbar what ever you want. Here I'm using brown , instead of this you can specify another color.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

Comment: Please format the code when posting. It helps the readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `setTintColor`